# write specific hour in a python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I need to pause a program until 08:00 of the following day, independently on the time the code is run. In other words if it is run at 08:00 today it will pause for 24h, but it was run at 20:00 it would be resumed at 08:00 of the following date.

Here is what I came up with:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
nowDateTimeObj = datetime.now()
tomorrow = nowDateTimeObj + timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow.hour = 8
```

Adding the 1 day time delta to the nowDateTimeObj datetime object works well to change the day to tomorrow but generates a time that's 24h relative to now. I want to take this "tomorrow" datetime object and set the hour part at 08:00

but I get the following error:

```
error: attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.datetime' objects is not writable
```

Comment: Not sure if it's best to reply with a comment or an answer. First time: The solution was to use the datetime.replace() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, I offer the example below just because it appears more readable to me.

```
from datetime import datetime, date

today = date.today()
tomorrow = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day+1)
tomorrow_8am = tomorrow.replace(hour=8)

print(today_date, tomorrow_8am)
```

Comment: Yes this is an alternative nice way to skin the same cat :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find the solution:

tomorrow = tomorrow.replace(hour=8)

Thank you all!